# How to write a function which includes numerical integration?

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I need to calculate the integration in many points. So,

```
f = f(r,theta,k,phi); 
q =integral2(f,0,1,0,2*pi,'AbsTol',0,'RelTol',1e-10); % integration should be by k and phi
```

I want the q to be a function of r and theta that I can call it anytime to calculate the integration in the given r and theta point. How can I do this?
The problem is that I couldn't use the indefinite @ function or matlabFunction() methods, because it seems that the integration is done first and when Matlab detects that it doesn't have all arguments defined, it brings some errors.

Comment: "...it brings some errors." – It would be helpful if you were specific. Your code is invalid unless the function `f` returns a function handle. Regardless, it's a bad idea to redefine `f`.

Comment: Yes, f is the handle. Integration takes the function handle which is the function of four variables. Errors were related to the argument to be function handle. Then I don't understand what is the proper way to define a function which will calculate the integration in many points which I give from mesh. I wrote in this way q =@(r,theta) integral2(f,0,2*pi,0,10,'AbsTol',0.01,'RelTol',1e-10), but I am not sure if this works OK. it is somehow an ugly solution I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this all you're looking for (I still don't know what `f` returns)?:

```
r = ...     % Define
theta = ... % Define
g = @(k,phi)f(r,theta,k,phi); % g is now a function of k and phi
q = integral2(g,0,1,0,2*pi,'AbsTol',0,'RelTol',1e-10);
```

This creates an anonymous function `g` where the values of `r` and `theta` are captured as parameters and `k` and `theta` are still arguments. This concept is known as a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29) in computer science.

If you want to turn the whole thing into a function of `r` and `theta` that returns `q` you can can create the following anonymous function:

```
q = @(r,theta)integral2(@(k,phi)f(r,theta,k,phi),0,1,0,2*pi,'AbsTol',0,'RelTol',1e-10);
```

that you can call with `q(r,theta)`. Of course you could equally just use normal functions (which are usually faster and make your code easier to understand by others).

Comment: f is a function f = @(r, theta, k, phi) g(r, theta, k, phi), where g is an expression. So, how to call q(r, theta) at some point?

Comment: ok. Thank you. This question is not related to the one in this discussion, but if I encounter "Warning: Reached the maximum number of function evaluations (10000). The result fails the global
error test. " this error, is there any page where this issue is discussed?

Comment: @artalexan: Try the [Tips section](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral2.html#btdesxy-4) in the documentation. You may need to play with tolerances. I also recommend this very recent [blog entry from the MathWorks](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2014/02/12/double-integration-in-matlab-methods-and-handling-discontinuities-singularities-and-more/) to learn more about double integration.